# How to append a git repository on top of another

Tags: git, tfs, tfvc, git-tfs

I am in the process of converting a project from TFS to git, and I want to keep all history.

The problem is that the TFS project was moved in TFS one year ago. 
Using git-tfs I can convert both locations to git, but now I have two git repositories: A and B.

I have managed to get both A and B into the same repository as different branches. Would it be possible to change the parent of first commit in B to the last commit in A?

```
Branch A: a -> b -> c
Branch B: d -> e -> f
```

I want to have

```
a -> b -> c -> d' -> e' -> f'
```

**Solution:**

```
git filter-branch --parent-filter 'sed "s/^\$/-p <last-commit-in-A>/"' HEAD_OF_B
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, set a `graft`, that does exactly that. If you are satisfied with the result you can do a `filter-branch` to make this permanently. Or you can use `filter-branch` right away with a `--parent-filter`.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two solutions:

1. Create a parent repository and add repositories A and B as submodules. You can learn more about this by reading the documentation for `git submodule`.
2. Add repository B as a remote to repository A:

   ```
   $ git remote add repoB <directory where repo B is located>
   ```

   Now you can fetch, pull, merge, and rebase from repo B, for example:

   ```
   $ git checkout master
   $ git pull repoB master
   ```

   (If it makes more sense, you can do this the other way around: add repo A as a remote to repo B. The same concepts apply.)

Comment: This does not work, since the git repositories doesn't share history. The last commit of A and the first commit of B has the exact same content. But their SHA1 hashes aren't the same. Both repos has been converted from TFS.

Comment: @sighol What do you mean by "doesn't work"? I used `git merge` as an example. Perhaps `git rebase` is more appropriate for your situation.

Comment: I don't think `git merge` or `git rebase` will work since the two branches have unrelated commits. 
Branch A: a -> b -> c
Branch B: d -> e -> f
The two brunches has totally unrelated histories. I want this history
a -> b -> c -> d' -> e' -> f'
I can't use rebase, since rebase will remove merge commits.

Comment: Well, `merge` can be used with unrelated histories using the `--allow-unrelated-histories` switch, but this is not what you actually want in your situation. And `rebase` can be used with any histories if you use the `--onto` switch, but again not really what you want in your situation. And you can also make `rebase` keep merge commits with `--preserve-merges` which *could* produce the result you want, especially if you don't reorder the commits. But again, not what you want in your situation. :-)