# Append TFS commits to existing git repository

Tags: git, tfs, git-tfs

I want to migrate repository from TFS to Git. I would like to setup the Git repository first (`.gitattributes`, LFS) and then start importing the TFS commits via `git-tfs`.

Unfortunately I haven't found the correct steps to do it. Is it even possible? The main goal is to avoid later filtering the whole imported repository (like `git lfs migrate import`).

When trying following:

```
git init
git lfs install
git lfs track *.bin
edit .gitattributes
export MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1
git tfs init http://tfs:1234/tfs/defaultcollection $/repo/path
git tfs fetch
```

Two trees are created (there are two root commits), which is not desirable.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to append a git repository on top of another.

Then you can :

> Set a `graft`, that does exactly that. If you are satisfied with the
>   result you can do a `filter-branch` to make this permanently. Or you
>   can use filter-branch right away with a `--parent-filter`.

Refer to this thread for details : [How to append a git repository on top of another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42860987/how-to-append-a-git-repository-on-top-of-another)

More information about git filter-branch please see [git-filter-branch - Rewrite branches](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch)